# Native NodeJS MongoDB driver opens additional connections

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I open a single connection to Mongo DB. After load test I can see multiple open connections from my app to Db.

Here is the code:

```
var app             = require('express')();
var logger          = require('log4js').getLogger();
var async           = require('async');

const logConnStr  = 'mongodb://mysite.com/logs';
const AppPort     = 10000;

logger.debug("Connecting to DB...");

function connectToLogs(cb) {
  MongoClient.connect(logConnStr, { server: {reconnectTries: 3000} }, function(err, db) {
    if ( err )
      return cb(err);
    cb(null, db);
  });
}


function getRoot(req, res) {
  var dbLogs = req.app.locals.dbLogs;
  dbLogs.collection('banners').count( function( err, count ) {
    if ( err )
      return res.json({status: false, result: err} );
    logger.debug(`Returning ${count}`);
    res.json({status: true, result: count} );
  });
}

function onDbInit(err, dbs) {
  assert.equal(err, null);
  logger.debug("Connected.");
  app.locals.dbLogs = dbs[0];
  app.get('/', getRoot);
  app.listen(AppPort);
  logger.debug(`Listening on ${AppPort}, pid=${process.pid}`);
}

async.series([
  connectToLogs
], onDbInit);
```

When application is run the number of connections to MongoDB is 1, as expected:

```
[root@njs ~]# lsof -p 19199 | grep TCP
node    19199 root   12u  IPv4 3024199246      0t0        TCP aaa.xxx.yyy.zzz:53535->aaa.xxx.yyy.zzz:27017 (ESTABLISHED)
node    19199 root   13u  IPv4 3024199307      0t0        TCP *:ndmp (LISTEN)
[root@njs ~]#
```

Then I load test the application with siege:

```
siege -r 10 -c 10 aaa.xxx.yyy.zzz:10000
```

and run `losof` again:

```
[root@njs ~]# lsof -p 19199 | grep TCP
node    19199 root   12u  IPv4 3024199246      0t0        TCP aaa.xxx.yyy.zzz:53535->aaa.xxx.yyy.zzz:27017 (ESTABLISHED)
node    19199 root   13u  IPv4 3024199307      0t0        TCP *:ndmp (LISTEN)
node    19199 root   14u  IPv4 3024238770      0t0        TCP aaa.xxx.yyy.zzz:53752->aaa.xxx.yyy.zzz:27017 (ESTABLISHED)
node    19199 root   15u  IPv4 3024238914      0t0        TCP aaa.xxx.yyy.zzz:53758->aaa.xxx.yyy.zzz:27017 (ESTABLISHED)
node    19199 root   17u  IPv4 3024238779      0t0        TCP aaa.xxx.yyy.zzz:53754->aaa.xxx.yyy.zzz:27017 (ESTABLISHED)
node    19199 root   18u  IPv4 3024238824      0t0        TCP aaa.xxx.yyy.zzz:53756->aaa.xxx.yyy.zzz:27017 (ESTABLISHED)
[root@njs ~]#
```

Where from are these connections?

The test system:

CentOS6, NodeJS 5.8.0, MongoDB 3.2 WiredTiger, NodeJS MongoDB driver 2.1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are not creating a single connection, you are creating a connection pool (which defaults to 5), see the [driver docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#connection-pool-configuration).